# Trying to Add SFTP Keyfile to FileZilla on Mac

Tags: key, public, filezilla

I'm trying to setup SFTP on FileZilla on a Mac and to add the keyfile, I need an actual file. I've gone through terminal and got the characters of the keyfile but how do I find the file itself or create a file with the characters of the key so that I can add it to FileZilla.

Hope that makes sense. Basically I can't copy and paste the key, I have to have a file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Shift-Command-Period to display hidden files and folders.  The .ssh folder will be in the users/you directory and the public key is inside it.  If it is password protected, you'll be prompted to save it without password because FileZilla doesn't support that type.